# jQuery - Assign a html code to a variable

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have a code like that

```
<p>hello</p>
```

I want to assign the above code to a variable, how to do that?

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly , do you want to store in a variable and append it later...

Comment: Sorry that my question is not clear, I just found the solution by using .html, thank you

Comment: basically you want html from dom , we have jquery .html which does that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var content = $('p').html();

Ah dammit, too late.

If you want a specific paragraph you should give it an id and use:

var content = $('p#id').html();

instead.

Comment: How to do the reverse process? Assign again the **var content** contents to **p**.
For example you needed to do a backup of p, modify it and recover the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "<p>hello</p>";
```

Comment: @srinivas , what will the above code get if you have two p elements in the page

Comment: he said assign that code to a variable not anything else so what does it matter if he has hundreds of them?

Comment: who and what? :P now you lost me

Comment: @breezer there was some code from someone called...srinivas which says $('p').html , i left the above comment for him...somehow it came for you

Comment: @gov it will give the first p data.After realizing that i deleted my answer.

Comment: oh oki i figured it was  something like that.